# Private network between two KVM VMs

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, proxmox

I'm trying to connect two KVM hosts together with a transparent ethernet link. I'm using Proxmox VE as the host and have configured 2 KVM VEs with ethernet interfaces and joined them to a single bridge (vmbr1).

I've configured static IP's on each of the hosts on the same subnet, though I'm unable to ping across the bridge (host A cant ping host B). The arp table on the VM is sporadically "Incomplete" and is yet to properly discover the other host.

If I induce the arp table with the other hosts mac and ip address the ICMP echo request is then seen on the bridge on the VM and the interface packet_in counters increase on the host I'm pinging.

I've seen a similar issue on ServerFault though following the following RedHat 'bug' didn't seem to have any effect: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=512206

Any ideas here?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with Proxmox but could you clarify please: You have two physical hosts, each one installed with Proxmox, meaning each of the two hosts is supposed to contain any number of virtual machines (VMs). Now you would like all of those VMs to be able to talk to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I abandoned linux bridges and installed and used OpenVSwitch, manually creating flows between the hosts using ovs-ofctl. Some odd behaviour with Linux bridges I'm not too sure about.